# Add plurals in one list and singulars in another list

Tags: python

I am working on a list with plurals and singulars. I want to create two separate lists: one list for plurals and one list for singulars.

```py
my_list = ['Accounts', 'Account', 'Accredited Investor', 'Accredited Investors', 'Issuer']
plurals = []
singulars = []
for a, b in itertools.combinations(my_list, 2):
    dist = levenshtein_distance(a, b)
    if dist == 1:
        if a[-1:] == 's':
            letter_with_s = a
            plurals.append(a)
        if b[-1:] == 's':
            letter_with_s = b
            plurals.append(a)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        print('False')
```

What I want is: `plurals = ['Accounts', 'Accredited Investors']`

What I get is: `plurals = ['Accredited Investor', 'Accredited Investor']`

Comment: You're appending `a` in both cases: `plurals.append(a)`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thank you, I just saw that too. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

this only for 's' case:

```
my_list = ['Accounts', 'Account', 'Accredited Investor', 'Accredited Investors', 'Issuer']
words = set(my_list)
plurals = [i for i in my_list if i[:-1] in words]
singulars = [i for i in my_list if i+'s' in words]
```